# How to add mandatory AMP HTML attribute to HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, gatsby, amp-html, react-helmet

I'm using [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com) and would like have my website identified an [AMP website](https://amp.dev/about/websites/).

How do I add the mandatory AMP attribute to the `<html>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add the mandatory AMP HTML attribute to your `<html>` tag using Gatsby, you may want to:

1. Customise your [`html.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/custom-html/) file by cloning the `.cache/default-html.js` to your `src/` directory.

   You can achieve that by running the command line below;

```sh
cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js
```

2. Then, add `amp=""` to the newly created `src/html.js` file as follows;

```html
<html amp="" {...props.htmlAttributes}>
```

Aside the option above, you can achieve same by simply adding the snippet below to your [`gatsby-ssr.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/) file;

```js
import React from "react"

// Adds an amp attribute to the <html> tag
export const onRenderBody = ({ setHtmlAttributes }) => {
  setHtmlAttributes({
    amp: ``,
  })
}
```